# Azure B2C Graph API : Set Account lock for User Wrong login attempts

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there's way to lock Azure B2C Account by sending API call from the code base? I need to write a function for following requirement

After 3 failed login attempts with a wrong password the account should be locked until user unlocked. it should be locked for defined time.

```
public async Task<string> LockUserAccount(string api, string query)
{

  AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", credential);


  HttpClient http = new HttpClient();


        **Here I need your help what kind of URL do i need to call here**
        > // string url = "https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant + api + "?" +

        >    
        >    //HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

     request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
     HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
               throw new WebException("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Formatting.Indented));
            }

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I have gone though with this Documentation and it says the lockout interval increases after further failed login attempts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout#manage-azure-ad-smart-lockout-values

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no related api to lock the user for defined time.

You also could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Azure team.

My workaround is that we could count the number of attempts. If the 3 failed login attempts then send the user information to [servicebus scheduled messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages). Then [update user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update) to set `accountEnabled`  **false**.

Afer that we could use the Azure function servicebus trigger to update user to set `accountEnabled` **true**